# How through operator overload to read data from file

Tags: c++

I need to develop a program in accordance with the task. I can’t figure out how to read data from a file using operator overloading and display them. It is necessary for each line, in theory, to assign its own variable. Those. user "person", day "day", month "month", year "year", message "message".

Develop a program for processing structural data types. Implement separate functions for input, output, search for information by some condition, sorting by some attribute.
E-MAIL box: MESSAGE sender, message text, sent dates. Sort by departure date in descending order. Display all messages from the specified sender.

In the code it will be necessary to sort by date and display the data of a specific user who will be entered, for this I need to assign "person" to each line with the sender, maybe even to each block to assign "message1", "message2". I don’t even know how it would be better here to sort and display later.

I'm not sure if I described the problem correctly, I don't know how to do it better here. I'm just new to programming, can you describe everything as simply as possible? I am a Russian-speaking user, can you not abbreviate the words so that I understand better?

This is the data part of the file

- Sender: Gilberto Brunelli
- Date(day, month, year):
- 25
- 03
- 2022
- Message: Buy bread
- Sender: Vincenzo Lorenzi
- Date(day, month, year):
- 13
- 04
- 2022
- Message: We're breaking up!
- Sender: Fabia Valentini
- Date(day, month, year):
- 19
- 04
- 2022
- Message: I love you<3
- Sender: Letizia Basso
- Date(day, month, year):
- 28
- 02
- 2022
- Message: You've been expelled

I have only a small code sketch

It's File.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "File.h"
using namespace std;
 
Message::Message() {
 
}
 
Message::Message(string Person, int Day, int Month, int Year, string Message){
    person = Person;
    day = Day;
    month = Month;
    year = Year;
    message = Message;
 
}
 
istream& operator >> (istream& input, Message& mes) {
    
    return input;
}
```

File.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H
 
 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
class Message {
private:
    int year, month, day;
    string message;
    string person;
public:
    Message();
 
    Message(string Person, int Day, int Month, int Year, string Message);
 
    void readFile();
 
    string getPerson();
    int getDay();
    int getMonth();
    int getYear();
    string getMessage();
 
    //перегрузка
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Message& mes);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& input, Message& mes);
};
 
#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "File.h"
 
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
 
    string path = "Mail.txt";
 
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path);
 
 
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Файл открыт" << endl;
    }
 
    string message;
 
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, message);
        cout << message << endl;
    }
 
    fin.close();
 
 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I am a Russian-speaking user, can you not abbreviate the words so that I understand better?"—are you aware of [ru.so]?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example code to read in the `Message` members.  Your Mileage May Differ:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& input, Message& mes)
{
    input >> mes.year;
    input >> mes.month;
    input >> mes.day;
    std::getline(input, mes.message);
    std::getline(input, mes.person);
    return;
}
```

You will need to modify the above code to match the data file.

This is only an example.